# WordPress Changing the Size , Color , Position of a text on scroll down

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

I would like to achieve the same effect as this example :
https://www.neom.com/en-us/sectors/energy

the Hero Header size and color change on scroll to the next section and became a header for that section .
how can i do it on wordPress and Elementor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found a solution and Create Example Here:
`codepen.io/moawia94/pen/XWqQNyy`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).